# Date diiference in days

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am subtracting two dates and I want to get the difference converted to days. How can I achive it?
I do it like below and it returns the result below, how can I convert the result as days?

```
article.created_at
#=> Fri, 05 Aug 2016 16:53:01 HKT +08:00

message.created_at
#=> Fri, 28 Aug 2015 07:59:43 HKT +08:00

article.created_at - message.created_at
#=> 29667198.69661808
```

Comment: Not too sure what your date format is, but I would try using `article.created_at.strftime("%d")`. This will return a string, so probably convert to integer if you plan on calculating something

Comment: Those are the values of dates I want to subtract. And I want the result will result computed as days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just divide by a day...

```
(article.created_at - message.created_at) / 1.day
#=> 343.3703472222222
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your `Time` (or `TimeWithZone`) objects to `Date` instances and invoke [`Date#-`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-2D) which returns the difference in days:

```
t1 = Time.parse('05 Aug 2016 16:53:01')
t2 = Time.parse('28 Aug 2015 07:59:43')

t1.to_date - t2.to_date
#=> (343/1)
```

Comment: `.to_i` for ruby >= 2.0